# Redirecting window page & tab to external website

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I having some browser issue opening new window tab to an external website.

What it's suppose to do: Current Window get redirected to a page while at the same time it open a new window tab and get redirected to an external page.

It works fine on Firefox, but not supporting IE or Chrome as in it doesn't open a new window tab and redirect. It does however redirect fine on the current window to the page I wanted. Anyone got idea why?

```
<script type="text/javascript">window.open('Site A');</script> (This doesn't open in IE, and Chrome open in a new window instead of tab)

<script>top.location.href="Site B"</script> (This line works fine in FF, IE, and Chrome)

<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try window.location instead of top.location.href.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Gustavo, but What I need is the first line of the script to open up on EI and Google Chrome. 2nd line works fine in IE,FF,Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine and in theory it should work,make sure the pop up is not blocked by browser.

Comment: I was able to get Chrome to open in a new window but did not have any web browser function (toolbar) above, but still can't get it to open in a new tab.

Comment: I found the reason. You're right. It's the pop up blocking the function for tab to open up and redirect. Any way to work around this Pop Up?

Comment: hehe, good to know you figured it out. Blocking pop up is really a internal browser behavior. A hacky way is to make the window.open a blank page in the same domain(same domain won't be blocked) and then in the blank page use window.location.href pointing to the external site. Not sure if there is any other better solution.